R DeSeq - problems generating heatmap graphs for RNA-Seq analysis
I'm analysing RNA-Seq datasets, but having problems generating heatmaps from the resulting data. I'm analysing two different groups of data from a larger dataset (E.g. Group1 vs Group2), but the heatmap insists on including all the samples in the entire dataset not just those I'm currently analysing.
Please can anyone demonstrate how to filter/select for specific comparison groups when doing RNA-Seq analysis and generating the resulting heatmap? I.e. heatmap comparing the two groups of samples I've actually analysed.

# Set working directory
setwd("C:/XXX")

# Read raw counts from file (e.g. .tsv)
rawCounts <- read.delim("RawCounts.tsv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1, comment.char = '#')

# Subset columns of interest
rawCounts <- rawCounts[, 6:ncol(rawCounts)]

# Set Ensembl dataset
mart <- useMart(biomart = 'ensembl', dataset = 'hsapiens_gene_ensembl')

# Get Ensembl data
ensembl <- getBM(attributes = c('ensembl_gene_id', 'external_gene_name', 'gene_biotype', 'description'),
                 mart = mart,
                 values = "protein_coding", 
                 filters = 'biotype')

# Filtering for protein-coding genes only
ensembl <- ensembl[ensembl$gene_biotype == 'protein_coding',]

# Filtering for raw counts/max counts
rawCounts <- rawCounts[row.names(rawCounts) %in% ensembl$ensembl_gene_id, ]
rawCounts <- rawCounts[apply(rawCounts, 1, max) >= 50, ]

##:  the rownames and colnames of the supplied assay(s) must be NULL or identical to those of the SummarizedExperiment object (or derivative) to construct
colnames(rawCounts) <- gsub(pattern = "Alignments.Oci_", replacement = "", colnames(rawCounts))
colnames(rawCounts) <- gsub(pattern = ".bam", replacement = "", colnames(rawCounts))

# DESeq2 setup
colData <- read.delim("Metadata.txt", sep = "\t", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)

# Check if Conditiongroup is present and properly formatted
if (!"Conditiongroup" %in% colnames(colData)) {
  stop("Conditiongroup column not found in colData.")
}

# Ensure Conditiongroup is a factor
colData[["Conditiongroup"]] <- as.factor(colData[["Conditiongroup"]])

# Create DESeqDataSet
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = rawCounts, colData = colData, design = ~ Conditiongroup)

# Run DESeq analysis
dds <- DESeq(dds)

# Extract results
res <- results(dds, contrast = c('Conditiongroup', 'Group1', 'Group2')) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  rownames_to_column(var = "ensembl_gene_id")

# Join results with Ensembl data
geneIDS <- inner_join(res, ensembl, by = "ensembl_gene_id")

# Write differential genes to a file
write.table(geneIDS, "Differential_genes.tsv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = "\t")

# Plotting log2FoldChange vs. -log2(padj)
plot(res$log2FoldChange, -log2(res$padj), pch = 20, xlab = "Log2 Fold Change", ylab = "-Log2 Adjusted P-Value")
abline(v = c(-1, 1), h = -log2(0.1), lty = 3)

# Estimate size factors and get normalized counts
dds <- estimateSizeFactors(dds)
normcounts <- as.data.frame(counts(dds, normalized = TRUE))

# Join normalized counts with Ensembl data
norm2 <- normcounts |> rownames_to_column(var = "ensembl_gene_id")
normcounts <- inner_join(norm2, ensembl, by = "ensembl_gene_id")

# Write normalized counts to a file
write.table(normcounts, "RNA_lognormcounts.tsv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = "\t")

# Correlation heatmap
corcounts <- normcounts [, c(2:3, 6:9)] # Adjust included columns if needed
corcounts <- log2(corcounts + 1)
cor <- cor(corcounts, method = "pearson")
##pheatmap(cor) 
pheatmap(cor, 
         color = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Blues"))(100),
         breaks=c(seq(0.6,1,length.out=100)), 
         show_colnames = F, 
         border_color = F)


# Filter for significant DEGs (adjust threshold if necessary)
significant_genes <- res[which(res$padj < 0.05 & abs(res$log2FoldChange) > 1), ]
# Upregulated genes (log2FoldChange > 1)
upregulated_genes <- res[which(res$padj < 0.05 & res$log2FoldChange > 1), ]

# Downregulated genes (log2FoldChange < -1)
downregulated_genes <- res[which(res$padj < 0.05 & res$log2FoldChange < -1), ]

# Volcano plot
volcano_plot <- ggplot(res, aes(x = log2FoldChange, y = -log10(pvalue))) +
  geom_point(aes(color = ifelse(padj < 0.05 & log2FoldChange > 0, "Upregulated", 
                                ifelse(padj < 0.05 & log2FoldChange < 0, "Downregulated", "Not Significant"))),
             size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Upregulated" = "red", "Downregulated" = "blue", "Not Significant" = "gray")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ##labs(title = "Volcano Plot", x = "Log2 Fold Change", y = "-log10(p-value)") +
  labs (title = NULL)
  theme(legend.position = "top")

# Get the normalized counts from DESeq2
dds <- estimateSizeFactors(dds)
normcounts <- as.data.frame(counts(dds, normalized = TRUE))

# Subset normalized counts for significant genes
sig_gene_names <- significant_genes$ensembl_gene_id
norm_sig_counts <- normcounts[sig_gene_names, ]

# Scale data for heatmap (z-score normalization by gene)
norm_sig_counts_scaled <- t(scale(t(norm_sig_counts)))

# Generate a heatmap for the differentially expressed genes (DEGs)
pheatmap(norm_sig_counts_scaled, 
         cluster_rows = TRUE, 
         cluster_cols = TRUE, 
         show_rownames = TRUE, 
         show_colnames = TRUE, 
         color = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "RdBu"))(100),
         annotation_col = colData,
         border_color = NA,
         main = "Heatmap of Differentially Expressed Genes")


#Finished Analysis

Code is attached. Every attempt results in a massive heatmap with all my data rather than just the groups I'm actually working on.

If I understand correctly you want to use log2FoldChange in your heatmap, this is part of the DESeq2 results() object (res in your script), you are plotting the (scaled) counts per sample.
